# Get text immediately after a tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently web scraping to find capacity numbers for certain venues.

Scraping through resident advisor and trying to grab the capacity number  which is visible in the html.

I can parse pretty close to it but I can no longer see the number I'm looking for

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://www.residentadvisor.net/club.aspx?id=4811', proxies={'http':'50.207.31.221:80'}).text  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

article = soup.find('ul', class_='clearfix')
for li in article.find_all('li'):
    for div in li.find_all('div'):
        print(div.text)
```

current out put from the code

```
Address /

Capacity /
Phone /
On the internet /
```

this is the html line

```
<li>
 <div>
  Capacity /
 </div>
 100
</li>
```

I'm trying to grab the 100 value.  How can I do that?

Comment: thanks guys,  I had to add a list to grab the character I wanted.             

`cap_lst = []  
cap = []
        article = soup.find('ul', class_='clearfix')
        for li in article.find_all('li'):
            cap.append(li.contents[1])
        cap_lst.append(cap[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = requests.get('https://www.residentadvisor.net/club.aspx?id=4811', proxies={'http':'50.207.31.221:80'}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    article = soup.find('ul', class_='clearfix')
    for li in article.find_all('li'):
        # print(li.text) -> shows all of the li text
        print(li.contents[1]) # shows the 100 under capacity
```

So the reason your code does not identify the 100 correctly is because you're calling div.text which will look for text in the div component. But in reality it is the second child of the li tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking things down, in this case you can use the sibling of the div tag:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """\
... <li>
...  <div>
...   Capacity /
...  </div>
...  100
... </li>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
>>> tag = soup.find('li')
>>> tag.find('div').next_sibling.strip()
'100'
```

Here, `tag.find('div').next_sibling` actually produces a `bs4.element.NavigableString` instance, a light subclass of `str` that is aware of its place in the DOM tree but has the same methods that `str` does.

As pointed out by @JackFleeting, an equivalent route would be `tag.contents[2].strip()`.